# Present subordinate clause using "when" followed by a main clause in the past

Tags: grammar, pronunciation, subordinate-clauses, when, songs

Recently, I've listened to [this version](https://youtu.be/LH0-WXUFY2k?t=102) (on YouTube) of Led Zeppelin's song *When the Levee Breaks*.  In this part of the song this guy sings "when the levee breaks, I **had** no place to stay", which is different from the original lyrics. Is this sentence correct? How can it be interpreted?

Also, if someone could transcript what is said at 2:55. I think it also differs from the original lyrics but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Too much screaming to tell. What are the original lyrics?

Comment: You can check it out [here](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/ledzeppelin/whentheleveebreaks.html)

Comment: From the written lyrics: 'When the levee breaks, we'll have no place to stay' and 'When the levee breaks, mama, you got to move ...'. The first example is typical, the second uses the (AAVE?) dramatic present-for-other-timeframes ('you got to move'), which sounds far more punchy than 'you will have to move'. But liberties are being taken with sprinklings of the dramatic switched tense.

Comment: I thought this type of construction using past simple following a subordinate "when" in the present was considered very ungrammatical. Could you give me another examples/usages of this structure?

Comment: Where did you get the idea it was ungrammatical? And why?